# Probability of Having wins

Tags: probability

During the last 15 games, James had a record of 12 wins and 3 losses. Assuming that he had a 50% chance of winning each game, what is the probability of having 12 wins and 3 losses in 15 games?

Comment: You may want to google "Binomial Distribution" first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the $15$ games, the total different number of ways in which he could win/lose is $2^{15}$ (win or lose, there are two possibilities for each game, and the games happen independent of each other). We can choose the $3$ games in which he lost in $\binom{15}{3}$ ways, and that gives that the probability must be $\dfrac{\binom{15}{3}}{2^{15}}$, which comes out to be $0.01388=\frac{455}{32768}$.

This  problem used the binomial distribution, which you can find out more about.